# Android rooted phone create app which scans and saves user's finger print in database

Tags: android, security, root, fingerprint, android-fingerprint-api

Well this is a question which many of them have asked. But it seems that there is no way we can read finger print scan and save it to our local database (as the answers in those questions suggest here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36022446/5675550 , https://stackoverflow.com/a/38179087/5675550).

I have made a sample app which scans user's finger print and authenticates users buy using android's native `FingerprintManager`.

I still want to know whether it is possible to read finger print and save it to the app's database and and maintain multiple user authentication. Like for example if `User1` taps his finger print, the app should identify as `User1` and if `User2` does the same, the app should identify as `User2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible with an external fingerprint readers with specific SDK, for instance:

- https://www.crossmatch.com/biometric-identity-solutions/products/hardware/single-finger-modules/
- https://www.morpho.com/fr/terminaux-biometriques/capteurs-de-bureau/capteurs-dempreinte-usb/morphosmart-serie-300

Or with specific Android Devices with specific SDK, for instance:

- http://logic-instrument.com/fr/fieldbook-m-series.php
- https://www.coppernic.fr/pda/c-one-e-id/

It's **not possible on consumer market devices**.

Comment: So there is no way I can achieve this with the consumer devices even with root access?

Comment: Very simple response: no